# $_POST to receive dynamic amount of fields to update

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I wasn't sure what to title this question.  Here's my goal:

On page one, I have a form that is generated from the database.  It loops through assigning a counting variable to the id of the fields (ie: header_1, header_2, header_3...)

Now, the amount of fields may vary as I need the ability to add extra information (ie: header_4, header_5).

When I submit my form, how can I create a variable for each field?

`$header1 = $_POST['header_1']`

Essentially, I am looking for an array-based (or variable variable-based) way of simplifying something like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE about SET about_header = '$head1', about_content = '$post1' WHERE about_id = '$id1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql="UPDATE about SET about_header = '$head2', about_content = '$post2' WHERE about_id = '$id2'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql="UPDATE about SET about_header = '$head3', about_content = '$post3' WHERE about_id = '$id3'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I imagine a query like this would work but I'm not sure how to handle the array of information that I would need help building as well.

```
$y=1;
$sql="UPDATE about SET about_header = '$head$y', about_content = '$post$y' WHERE about_id = '$id$y'";
```

I hope I explained this well enough.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Please, paste your HTML form.

Comment: Please use `mysqli` or `PDO`, as the `mysql_*` family of functions [are deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you ever tried something like:

```
<input name="header[]" />
<input name="header[]" />
<input name="header[]" />
```

This will create a multi-dimensional array on the PHP side which you can easily cycle through.

```
echo $_POST['header'][0];
echo $_POST['header'][1];
echo $_POST['header'][2];
```

It would also be faster to use prepared statements for this, although you would have to switch to using something like PDO for your database interactions. Here's an example of looping thorugh using the code you showed above.

```
$fieldCount = count($_POST['header']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $fieldCount; $i++) {
   $sql = 'UPDATE about SET about_header = \''.$_POST['header'][$i].'\', about_content = \''.$_POST['post'][$i].'\' WHERE about_id = \''.$_POST['id'][$i].'\'';
   mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: How would I go about updating the fields with that though?

Comment: @Yuschick The same way you are doing above, except inside of a loop where you are looping through the input items.

Comment: @Yuschick see my edit. as i said though, prepared statements with something like PDO would get you much better performance for something like this.

Comment: Wow.  That looks so simple.  So name my form fields to fir the array 'header[]', it counts how many headers are POSTed and loops for each one.  I think that's what I was looking for.  Thanks.  I'll keep you post on implementation of this.

Comment: @Yuschick keep in mind you will want to ensure that you sanitize your POST vars to protected from SQL injection, and it couldn't hurt to add some error checking to your DB calls as well.

Comment: An absolute charm!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="head[]" />
<input type="text" name="head[]" />
<input type="text" name="head[]" />

<?php
foreach ($_POST['head'] as $head) {
    // ....
}
?>
```

Naming your inputs like this (note the array-ish notation) will yield

```
$_POST == array( 'head' => array(
  0 => FIRST TEXT DATA,
  1 => SECOND TEXT DATA,
  2 => THIRD TEXT DATA
))
```

Comment: During that foreach loop, with the variables end like $head[1], $head[2]...?